# No Account Controller views in VS.2015 MVC with WebAPI?

Tags: oauth-2.0, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition and created a Web project using MVC and Web API (both selected) with Individual User Account as authentication method.

I noticed that the scafolded template varies in some ways, I now see an AccountBindingModels.cs file, I do see the Account Controller class but I see it references the /api path rather than the usual /Account and I do not see any Account Controller views.

So, if there are no account controller views how can I add supplemental profile information if there is no view to modify?

I also do not see the usual "Log In" link that was at the top of the page layout. I only see an API link at the top next to Home but it takes me to a Help area. If I attempt to go to /api/Account/Register I am asked if I want to save or open Register.

I have invested quite some time on other modifications and now I notice this so it would be very unproductive to start again from scratch.

Basically I want to be able to use both webapi and MVC to perform authenticated requests. I don't see how users can login on the MVC site or even request protected views because there seems to be no login form on the MVC5 website.

Comment: I think you have chosen Web API template instead of MVC template when created the project.
Please try again and be sure that you select MVC template.

Comment: I chose both, you can choose to have both WebAPI and MVC. The idea is also to have authorization on both MVC and web API and I believe that is precisely the move in 5.2.

Comment: Yes, you can chose both, but be sure that in "Select a template" select the MVC template instead of Web API template, and then select "Add folders and core references for"  MVC and Web API. I hope it helps.

Comment: And how can I add that once it was templated? I am afraid I have already spent several weeks implementing the site to wipe everything out and start out with a new template. Any way to add what is missing?

Comment: You can add it manually, for example create a new project with the correct template and then add all the scaffolded code to your project manually.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue.  Got around it by choosing MVC template and then checking the Web API check box in the "Add folders and core references for:" check box area.
So, MVC and Web API are checked.  This gives me the account views and more scaffolding.

If I choose the Web API template, it defaults to both MVC and Web API checked.  But does not give me the account views and ...  Maybe that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today and I was using the VS 2015 Enterprise. @jumoro was right, you have to add the MVC template (not the WebAPI one) and it will add all the account related views. At least it does that in the Enterprise edition.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to download the [Nuget Identity Sample](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples), which will provide you with the necessary model, controller and views.